# How do i print only the 'sequence' of the following code?

Tags: python

[Piece of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0n1k.png)

I want print only the sequence whenever i use code. So i tried using .['sequence'] but it didnt work. What change do i do in the code?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the returned object for `unmasked(text)` is similar to:

```
text = 'Where is the room with temperature [MASK]'
unmasked(text) = [
    {'score': 0.4, 'token': 136, 'sequence': 'Where is the room with temperature?.'}, 
    {'score': 0.2, 'token': 1723, 'sequence': 'Where is the room with temperature change'},
    {'score': 0.15, 'token': 19828, 'sequence': 'Where is the room with temperature changes?'}
]
```

So the result is actually of type 'list' and not type 'dict' so you cannot do `result['sequence']`.

If you do `result[0]`, you will get a dictionary object = `{'score': 0.1, 'token': 136, 'sequence': 'Where is the room with temperature?.'}`

Then if you do `result[0]['sequence']` you will get the string `'Where is the room with temperature?.'`

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to get only the `"sequence"` attribute of each `dict`:

```py
masked_data = unmasker("Where is the room with temperature [MASK]")
sequences = [datapoint["sequence"] for datapoint in masked_data]
```

For printing, you can either print the whole array with `print(sequences)` or print each sequence on its own line with:

```py
for sequence in sequences:
    print(sequence)
```

Comment: great to hear! please upvote and mark the answer as correct :)